# Java: [Performance] Storing and searching <Integer, Integer> for the most occuring one

Tags: java, performance, sorting, optimization, integer

I have this Problem and solving it is not the problem, more like what is the fastest way doing it.
So i am asking the more experienced of you to help me find a fast solution.

I have People, each defined as a Integer between 1000 and 3000.
Every of these people can be assigned to someone else, this would look like:
<Integer for p1, Integer for p2>
There are some rules for these connections, there will be not more than 10000, but at least one of them 
and each pair of people can only occur once, so <1000,2000> and <2000,1000> are not allowed!
At the Moment i store all of these connections in a LinkedList where Connection is a Class containing the two Integers of the two people.

I then need to find the person occuring the most times in all connections, if there are more than one, i would need to have all of them unsorted.

After that, i will iterate through the LinkedList and delete all connections where these people participated and redo the process until the list is empty.

Some problems i encountered are Concurred Access or use of the wrong Maps/Lists and a slow method of sorting.

I have no code at the moment, since i saw the performance of my old one and started from scratch with now nothing other than processing the input (witch is already optimized) ;)

What would help me most is someone looking at my case and telling me his experiences of how fast different solutions with different Datatypes are. I want to write the code mostly myself, i just need some hints how to do it right.

Thanks for the attention and hopefully for an answer.
If something is unclear, i appologise for that and will clarify it upon asking :)

Comment: You want both a `Set` of `Connection` objects, and a `Map` from every Person in the set to the `Connection`s it's part of. Both of these are O(1) for searching, you'll just have to wrap both in your own class to ensure they're consistent. (I'll see if I can hack up some code.)

Comment: LinkedList in java has pretty abysmal performance for most tasks in comparison to ArrayList. The one thing it does excel in comparison to ArrayList is when you are doing lots of insertions/deletions in the  middle of the list via a ListIterator. If you don't use a ListIterator then performance is terrible again.

Comment: I believe I saw this exact same question in SO a few months ago - smells like homework ...

Comment: @RonK I'm sorry if i asked a question that was already answered, but i had searched some time before starting the question.
And, thrust me or not, this is no homework. Like i said, i already found a solution for the problem i encountered and i just thought of the awful performance and asked for some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at this the object oriented way, we can have each Person store a List of their friends:

```
class Person {
    private Set<Person> friends = new HashSet<>();

    public void addFriend(Person newFriend) {
        friends.add(newFriend);
        newFriend.friends.add(this);
    }

    public void removeFriend(Person oldFriend) {
        friends.remove(oldFriend);
        oldFriend.friends.remove(this);
    }

    public int numberOfFriends() {
        return friends.size();
    }

    public void disappear() {
        for (Person friend : friends) {
            friend.friends.remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that all operations complete in constant expected time.

This is much better than keeping a linked list of a friendships where finding the number of friends of a single person requires us to go through the list of all 10000 friendships.

It is also significantly faster than the two-dimensional array described by rogelware, where finding the number of friends requires checking all 2000 other persons for friendship, and removing a person requires clearing the friendship to all 2000 other persons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for how far i can see, this seems to be the most elegant solution for now, will try it and see, if i get it written right

Comment: One problem i have with your solution is getting the right hashcode-method for your Person-class since it refers to a HashSet of itself.
Perhaps it wuld help to simply give evry person a ID and using this id for the hash, that would be a bit hacky but gives fast and unique hashes

Comment: Why would that be hacky? If I want to know whether somebody is Joe, I don't ask the somebody and Joe who their friends are so I can compare them - and I definitely don't ask about their friends' friends. I simply ask for their ID and compare it with Joe's.

Comment: You're right, i simply forgot about every person having a unique id, which is predefined before execution, so this should go fine

Comment: Considering an object oriented approach, this solution is better. Considering best performance, using arrays is better. The count issue can be solved with an array of ints that keeps the number of friends.

Comment: {citation needed} for your performance claim. In particular, the choice of algorithm has a far greater effect on performance than replacing objects with arrays ever could.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is an undirected graph. That there exist a set nodes with connections between, and each connection bidirectional.

There are four common representations for graphs that can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29#Representations).

You need to decide which representation best suits your needs and whether it can be adapted to give a performance increase.

My recommendation would be to use adjacency lists, but have each node store one list of all the nodes it links to, and another list of all the nodes that link to it.

eg.

```
class Node {

    Integer personID;
    List<Integer> links;

}

// graph data type
Map<Integer, Node> graph;
```

Now, due to the how the data is stored, find out how many total connections a person has becomes as simple as:

```
Integer personID = ...;
Node n = graph.get(personID);
int totalConnections = n.links.size();
```

All you then need to is create a list of objects that store both the person id and how many links they have in total and then sort by total links (which will group all the high total links counts at the end of the list).

You would, of course, have to make sure that the graph data is properly built in the initialisation phase.

One thing to bear in mind is that this representation will increase the memory complexity of your graph somewhat, but significantly reduce the time complexity of your algorithm. What do you value more in your program, time or memory?

However, depending on how dense the connections are in your graph an adjacency matrix might better suit your needs.

### Other issues:

LinkedList in java has pretty abysmal performance for most tasks in comparison to ArrayList. The one thing it does excel in comparison to ArrayList is when you are doing lots of insertions/deletions in the middle of the list via a ListIterator. If you don't use a ListIterator then performance is terrible again. Due to implementation of LinkedLists, the default sorting algorithm in the java Collections API has very poor performance at sorting LinkedLists;

Concurrent access exceptions with the collections API occur when using a foreach loop and modifying the collection during the loop. You need to loop over the collection with an Iterator or ListIterator and add/remove elements via the Iterator/ListIterator.

Comment: Whoops, didn't read the "not" you put in there. However. the directionality of the edges has little significance on the overall solution.

Comment: It means you need to prevent duplicates somehow. The general idea is indeed the same though.

Comment: I was leaving that up to Kostronor solve when he coded his solution, but Meriton's use of Sets is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If space is not a problem i would use a matrix to store the connections.

The first dimension is p1 and the second one is p2. I would have a

```
boolean[][] connection = new boolean [2001][2001];
```

(i will consider from 0 to 2000).

When there is a connection between 455 and 985 i would have to check the both directions.. For example:

```
connection[455][985] = true;
connection[985][455] = true;
```

If I want to test if there's a connection between two persons i would do

```
 if(connection[455][985]) //the other end will have the same values
```

This would waste too much space, but it would be really fast and easy to work with.

Comment: This is a good Idea,

But i need to find the most occuring person, so i would have to go:

while(p1 < 2000){
while(p2 < 2000){
if(connection[p1][p2]){
//increment something, perhaps a map? storing all persons and how ofthe they occur.

Comment: You could store only half of the matrix if you always use the lower value as the first index to set and to test the matrix. But a more complex code is needed. For example, if you have 963 and 223. You would use it like [223][963], so you would not have to store the [963][223] value.

Comment: The simplest solution to that would be storing the number of connections for each person in an integer. An array like this for the people: int[] numberOfConnections = new int[2001]. Then you encapsulate all this stuff in a class and increment/decrement the persons connection count as needed.

Answer (score 0):

A rough outline of what I meant in my comment:

#### Person

```
class Person {
    long id;

    Person(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // Compare by id
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // Hash by id
    }
}
```

#### Connection

```
class Connection {
    Person person1;
    Person person2;

    Connection(Person person1, Person person2) {
        if (person1.equals(person2)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot connect a person to itself");

        if (person1.id < person2.id) {
            this.person1 = person1;
            this.person2 = person2;
        } else {
            // The person1 field should contain the person with the smaller id
            this.person1 = person2;
            this.person2 = person1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // Compare person1 and person2
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // Hash person1 and person2
    }
}
```

#### ConnectionManager

```
class ConnectionManager {
    Set<Connection> connections = new HashSet<Connection>();
    Map<Person, Set<Person>> adjacency = new HashMap<Person, Set<Person>>();

    public void connect(Person p1, Person p2) {
        Connection connection = new Connection(p1, p2);
        if (connections.add(connection)) {
            getAdjacency(p1).add(p2);
            getAdjacency(p2).add(p1);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Persons %d and %d are already connected", p1.id, p2.id));
        }
    }

    private Set<Person> getAdjacency(Person person) {
        Set<Person> result = adjacency.get(person);
        if (result == null) {
            adjacency.put(person, result = new HashSet<Person>());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void disconnect(Person p1, Person p2) {
        if (connections.remove(new Connection(p1, p2))) {
            getAdjacency(p1).remove(p2);
            getAdjacency(p2).remove(p1);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("No connection between persons %d and %d exists", p1.id, p2.id));
        }
    }

    public Collection<Map.Entry<Person, Set<Person>>> getMostConnected() {
        int maxConnections = 0;
        List<Map.Entry<Person, Set<Person>>> result = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Person, Set<Person>>>();
        // return all the entries with the maximum size;

        for (Map.Entry<Person, Set<Person>> entry : adjacency.entrySet()) {
            int connections = entry.getValue().size();

            if (connections > maxConnections) {
                result.clear();
                maxConnections=connections;
            }

            if (connections == maxConnections) {
                result.add(entry);
            } 
        }

        return result;
    }


    public Set<Person> getConnections(Person person) {
        return new HashSet(getAdjacency(person));
    }
}
```

Getters/setters, and `equals()`/`hashCode()` implementations are omitted for brevity - whatever the IDE generates for the latter is fine.

This code is essentially a matrix, represented with an adjacency list. The only part of it that's not O(1) is the part that searches for the person with the most connections, which is O(n).

You could reduce that performance hit by using a `PriorityQueue` holding the `Set<Person>` objects that are stored in the `adjacency` map, with the set size as the "priority". Anytime such a set is about to be touched, remove it from the queue, change it, and insert it again. (My hunch however is that this would only make getting the most connected person faster by making connecting and disconnecting people slower.)

Disclaimer: the above code is completely untested, it's just to give you an idea of what you could try.

Comment: Bah, I missed the part where you mention you need all the people having the maximum connection count.

Comment: Erm, it's really not necessary to sort to find a maximum, or even all maxima. Simply iterate the list, and keep track of the biggest element (all all equally big elements) encountered so far. The JDK does contain a mutable collection that allows efficient retrieval of the maximum element: PriorityQueue.

Comment: ... and if I were to implement a PriorityQueue, I'd use a *heap*, not a binary search tree.

Comment: @meriton Right you are. Drilling data structures and algorithms sometimes makes one forget that a linear search isn't always bad. I forgot about PriorityQueue. Since it's a heap, removing an element should be O(n), which might make a tree faster when adding/removing connections. (Of course it might not, or not enough to make it worth messing with a third-party tree implementation.) I'll correct the code in my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use LinkedList, use integer array of 2 elements, or special class of two fields.

```
class Relation {

    private int id1, id2;

    public Relation(int id1, int id2) {   
         if( id1 > id2 ) {   
             this.id2 = id1;
             this.id1 = id2;
         }
         else {
             this.id1 = id1;
             this.id2 = id2;
         }
    }


    public int hashCode() { 
        return id1 ^ id2;
    }

    public boolean equals(object o) {
        return 
             ((Relation)o).p1 == p1 &&
             ((Relation)o).p2 == p2;
    }

}
```

Last two methods are for working with `HashSet` if you need to check uniqueness.

Then put all your relations into `HashSet<Relation>`, also back up them into some linear structure like array or `Vector<Relation>`